# Pattern involved in target name in make file

Tags: makefile

I want to execute multiple targets for the list of servers. From makefile output it seems only $(SERVERS) target executed twice. I want Launch-% to be executed twice. How can I make it work. How can I access each IP address in target Launch-%? Please help me out. I have following make file source code and output. Thanks in advance.

```
Makefile source code:
SERVERS=172.16.0.17 172.16.0.100
test-all: test-port-connectivity
test-port-connectivity: Launch-$(SERVERS)
        echo "Test suit 1: Port Connectivity $<"

Launch-%: $(SERVERS)
        echo "Launch Server $<"

$(SERVERS):
        echo "Server IP - $@"

Output of Makefile:
# make 
echo "Server IP - 172.16.0.17"
Server IP - 172.16.0.17
echo "Server IP - 172.16.0.100"
Server IP - 172.16.0.100
echo "Launch Server 172.16.0.17"
Launch Server 172.16.0.17
echo "Test suit 1: Port Connectivity Launch-172.16.0.17"
Test suit 1: Port Connectivity Launch-172.16.0.17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SERVERS=172.16.0.17 172.16.0.100
LAUNCHES=$(addprefix Launch-, $(SERVERS)) # this will be Launch-172.16.0.17 Launch-172.16.0.100

test-all: test-port-connectivity
test-port-connectivity: $(LAUNCHES)
    echo "Test suit 1: Port Connectivity $^"

$(LAUNCHES): Launch-%: %
    echo "Launch Server $<"

$(SERVERS):
    echo "Server IP - $@"
```

Notice that the `$(LAUNCHES)` rule is a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). (A simpler [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) would also suffice, but not be as tidy.) Also notice the use of [`$^`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) in the `test-port-connectivity` rule.

Comment: In LAUNCH recipe I generate another run time LIST which I want to process similar to $(SERVERS) list. Is there any way I can transfer control from $(LAUNCH) recipe to some other target in the file?

Comment: @ashinde: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry Beta for not making it clear. I had file new question for this because of text limitation. Here is the link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501880/process-runtime-gerated-list-in-makefile"